# How can I unwrap a module with SocksiPy?

Tags: python, module, proxy, urllib2, socks

I use the [SocksiPy](http://code.google.com/p/socksipy-branch/) module to proxy my urllib2 requests through a SOCKS proxy:

```
import socks

# Set the proxy information
socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, 'x.x.x.x', 9050)

# Route an HTTP request through the SOCKS proxy 
socks.wrapmodule(urllib2)

print urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com').read()

# other urllib2 requests to follow here..
```

Maybe my question is very simple: How can I **unwrap** the urllib2 module from the `socks` one,
so as the following urllib2 requests to be made from localhost (without the proxy support)
and maybe without set call the `setdefaultproxy` without arguments?

I tried to import the urllib2 lib again but nothing happened..

I see that it works fine after I call this:

```
setdefaultproxy()
```

But is this the right way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use my Socksipy branch with the urllib2 helper library here: https://github.com/Anorov/PySocks

Example code, for your case:

```
import socks, urllib2
from sockshandler import SocksiPyHandler
proxy_opener = urllib2.build_opener(SocksiPyHandler(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "IP", 9050))
print proxy_opener.open("http://whatismyip.org/").read()
```

You can set different openers to use different proxies, or in your case, you can simply use a default urllib2 handler or urllib2.urlopen and it won't connect through the proxy.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I wanted to do.. I have already changed my code to use human_curl for the cases that the requests require a socks proxy, but now I think it's better to change again the code and follow your example! Thank you!

Comment: So you have implemented it! Great! This is a good solution and it will work with multiple threads. You can have a different opener per thread. Otherwise, with the old approach of `Socksipy` you had to change the global socket of the urllib2: but this would break the thread safety, that is you would have all your requests go through the same proxy in all of your threads..

Comment: hmm.. Maybe I should keep the `human_curl` implementation. I try a `socks4` proxy through human_curl and everything works fine, but through your `sockshandler` a `socks4Error` is raised: `(91, 'Request rejected or failed')`.

Comment: @ThanasisPetsas Do other proxy servers (SOCKS5, HTTP) work? Could you paste your code somewhere so I can look at it?